# Password Gorilla will not launch after my 18.04 update.

Tags: upgrade

Password Gorilla will not launch after 18.04 upgrade. No error messages apparent.

Comment: It outputs                 jim@jim-pc:~$ password-gorilla
/usr/share/password-gorilla/gorilla.tcl: 3: exec: tclsh: not found
jim@jim-pc:~$

Comment: I'm not familiar with tcl. Is this a new requirement for 18.04? If so how do I install it.

Comment: I reinstalled tcl. Password gorilla now works. Thanks